# How to add content while creating custom button/link which is mandatory, i selected content source as visualforce page.

Tags: visualforce

here i am pasting image which contains the error.
as a fresher i am unable to get answer for the error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create a custom button on a **Custom** object. The option **Content Source** you've selected is a **Visualforce Page** which means that you should have any **Visualforce page** defined with **Standard Controller**. Since you haven't defined any Visualforce page with standard controller you are not getting any value under that dropdown. And it is mandatory to select any VF page if you've selected **Content Source** as **Visualforce Page**. This will make sure that when you click on your button selected Visualforce page will be open.

For more details refer [standard doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_tabs.htm).

As per your question, how to add a **Content**, answer is; you need to create a VF page with standard controller. Refer below example:

I've defined a Visualforce Page with standard controller for **Expense** Object. Visualforce Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="light002__Expense__c">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

Creating a new Custom **Search** button:

[image]

Comment: I don't know why this custom button bind to standard controller's VF page?

Comment: @surendranaidu Because you've selected VF page option on Content source for that particular object. Which means you need to provide source from where data will be displayed when user clicks on that button. Your VF page will provide necessary data which will be shown.