# Override View button with a visualforce page or lightning component in salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I was working in salesforce classic and i override view button on contact with a visualforce page :

And when i open the same page in lightning its giving the same look and feel as of classic and yes its not following the lightning rules also like i placed a onClickjavascript button in page layout and now my contact detail page showed js button.

So i thought of making changes to my VFP page by checking if that page is opening in classic or lighinig by using *$User.UIThemeDisplayed* in my page.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/units/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages

I was thinking to use force:recordView
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordView.htm

but in this link its mentioned it won't work with Lightning Out properly.

--------App-----------

```
<aura:application access="global" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:contactDetailPAge"/>
    <c:contactDetailPAge />
</aura:application>
```

------cmp--------------

```
<aura:component>
    <force:recordView recordId='0033600000GtRskAAF' type="FULL"/>
</aura:component> 

<!--Hardcoded the id just for checking-->
```

---------VFP--------------

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:detail />
</apex:page>
```

This is my vfp page that i need to modify to include the lightning component which displays will display detail page of contact record.

So, my app is not loading and if i remove extends="ltng:outApp" from my application file it works fine.

So i dont think this way will work as i can only override the view button with a visualforce page(i need to display this component through my visualforce page).

So is there is any way i can achieve this?
need to display my contact detail page as other standard detail page in lightning through a visualforce page.

Comment: for overriding standard button with VF page refer [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163952/how-to-add-content-while-creating-custom-button-link-which-is-mandatory-i-selec/163955#163955)